# Clickable Multilevel menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to do an menu like this one http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-level-dropdown-menu-bs3, it has to be multilevel menu but I would like to open the menu only with clicks, also the multilevel items, not with on mouse over. Also if the menu is open and make click on the body will close all the menu. Anyone have any idea?

Thanks in advance.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <a id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#" href="/page.html">
                Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
              <li><a href="#">Some action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Some other action</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Hover me for more options</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Second level</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                    <a href="#">Even More..</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">3rd level</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">3rd level</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Second level</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Second level</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}


.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color: #ccc;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
    border-left-color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
    float: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
    left: -100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}
```

JS

```
$(function(){
    $(".dropdown-submenu").on("click",function(e){
    var current=$(this).find(".dropdown-menu");
        current.toggle();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Comment: Ofcourse. Resign with `:hover` in css and write click event function in JavaScript.

Comment: Hehhe yes u are right I was looking at the .dropdown-submenu:hover and I have to change it for a function onclick on the dropdown-submenu.

Comment: I already did it but all the multilevel menu are opens when I click on the body page.

Comment: Try use `.next()` or `.first()` instead `.find()`

Comment: Yes I tried and does not work :(

Answer (score 1):

The solution is:

JS

```
$(function(){
    $(".dropdown-submenu").on("click",function(e){
    var current=$(this).find(".dropdown-menu").first();
    console.log(current);
        current.toggle();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });


 $(document).click(function(){
   $(".dropdown-menu").hide('slow'); 
});


});
```