# Facing Css issue in multi Level Menu

Tags: css, angular

I am trying to build a multi level side navigation menu and i am able to complete it but some css issue is coming please suggest me way to get it done and any kind of code enhancement which i can do

[code link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-giahxn)

I want to create a multi menu side nav like below

[image]

[image]

1) But the problem is that sub childs are already opened which should be closed and only open on clicking parent

2) And this is happening because i have below css in my app.component.css

```
.active  ul{
  display:block !important;
}
```

I don't know much about css so not able to solve css problem.

Comment: is it okay if the submenu is collapsed when clicked on the submenu at the same level

Comment: Please define the exact behavior you expect, since I've noticed in your example that opening a menu closes the other open ones, etc.

Comment: @ethanfar i want menues to be closed at first and on clicking a menu it will show its childs and if childs also have sub childs than to open sub child we need to click on child and same process for closing menus

Comment: if one menu is open, what should happen if you click on a another menu at the same level, should the not clicked menu get closed or remian open?

Comment: it can be either closed or open. If you know how to do it please suggest

Comment: Can't you use material menu ?

Comment: Why not just keep the expanded state of the menu as part of the data ? This way, when you open a menu, it's submenus will be open/closed according to their previous state. Doesn't make more sense that to keep closing and opening the submenus ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS should be targeting only the child element whose parent has ***.active*** class,

```
.active > app-submenu > ul {
  display: block !important;
}
```

We need to modify the ***app.component*** and ***submenu.component*** (*both HTML and TS*)

Now to make this work on clicking the parent elements, we need a variable which will tell us which ***li*** is selected, we can use data attribute of the element to save its state, instead of creating a new variable.

```
<li [attr.data-selected]="false"> /* content */ </li>
```

and to access it we give an ***angular ID*** to the element and pass it as arguement in the ***NgClass***

```
<li #thisLiElement [attr.data-selected]="false" [ngClass]="setActiveClass(thisLiElement)"> /* content */ </li>
```

Now the data attribute needs to be updated when clicked upon.

```
<li *ngFor="let menu of navItems" (click)="clickedEvent($event); $event.stopPropagation();" #thisLiElement [attr.data-selected]="false" [ngClass]="setActiveClass(thisLiElement)">
```

The defination for ***clickedEvent*** and ***setActiveClass*** are as follows, which toggles on current elements ***dataset***

```
clickedEvent(event){
  if (event.currentTarget["dataset"].selected === "false")
    event.currentTarget["dataset"].selected = "true";
  else 
    event.currentTarget["dataset"].selected = "false";
}

setActiveClass(thisLiElement) {
  return thisLiElement.dataset.selected === "true" ? { "active": true } : { "active": false };
}
```

**Note:** The mat-icon ***if conditions*** should be also updated for above change as follows

```
<mat-icon *ngIf="menu.children && menu.children.length > 0">{{iconState(thisLiElement)}}</mat-icon>
```

and the defination for iconState should be,

```
iconState(thisLiElement) {
  return thisLiElement.dataset.selected === "true" ? "expand_less" : "expand_more";
}
```

Also there is no need for ***@output*** in submenu component, so i have removed the ***emitter*** and the function ***subMenuClicked***

Updated StackBlitz over [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tzzcnj).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much Vipul you saved my day.one more help you can do.I also need to highlight parent with css if child is clicked like if angular9 is clicked than it’s both parent Angular+ and Angular have some css

Comment: glad I could help, i'll update the stackBlitz as soon as possible for highlighting the parent link.

Comment: updated the [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tzzcnj), check the submenu component and its HTML, CSS, its partially done, you will need to tweak it further

Comment: Thanks Vipul for your help

Answer (score 1):

You have to JavaScript code like this,

```
$(function(){
    $(".dropdown-submenu").on("click",function(e){
    var current=$(this).find(".dropdown-menu").first();
    console.log(current);
        current.toggle();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });


 $(document).click(function(){
   $(".dropdown-menu").hide('slow'); 
});


});
```

For more reading:
1) [Clickable Multilevel menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38589931/clickable-multilevel-menu)
2) https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_dropdown_multilevel_css&stacked=h